# PHP exec on Windows with IIS

Tags: php, iis, exec, application-pool

I'm running my code in windows machine with IIS and PHP 5.2. 
I did some configuration (images below) and still not work.

This is my simple code:

```
<?php 
    ini_set("display_errors", "On");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    ini_set("log_errors", 1);
    ini_set("error_log", "./logs/php-error.log");

    echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

**I only receive a white page, nothing more. (no errors)**

What i'm doing wrong?

[image: Authentication]

[image: Pool Permissions]

[image: Pool Settings]

PS: I tried with xampp and works great, but with IIS no.

Comment: i tried your code which is working well at my side. also shows the user [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXJ9H.png) , try to assign iis user permission to the C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe file. [php 5.2 end of life](https://www.php.net/eol.php) try to use the latest PHP version.

Comment: please hide the sensitive information from the snapshot.

Comment: I can' change permission of cmd.exe
With this option, works well:
```exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c start /B php generate.php");```
@JalpaPanchal what information are you talking about?
PS: Is impossible change php version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solution for my problem:

**First:**

```
exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c start /B php generate.php");
```

**Second (alternative):**

```
$handle = new COM('WScript.Shell');
$handle->Run('php generate.php', 0, false);
```

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//d5fk67ky(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN